# Kubernetes - KOPS - How to use the existing Route tables and SecGroups on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

Just wanted to know how to use the existing Route Tables and SecGroups on aws while creating the KOPS cluster. I can create using the existing VPC and Subnet by giving their ids, but it creates a new route table and my subnet is already attached to a different route table.

Any idea about this?